# JNIPort - How to load this in pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I was trying to load JNIPort in pharo , from

MCHttpRepository
    location: 'http://www.squeaksource.com/JNIPort'
    user: ''
    password: ''

Its raising some bugs regarding missing .mcz files in the repo. I wonder if sommone is using it already, and are willing to share info about loading it to the image.

My objective is feasibility study.

Comment: SqueakSource is currently moving on a new server and migrating to new Squeak version, so it is better to wait a week or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could never install JNIPort, but Masashi Umezawa prepared a Pharo 1.4 image with JNIPort installed in it. You can find it here:

http://share.cx.com/Cgpfpv

I know it's not exactly the answer you were looking for, but at least you'll have a Pharo image with JNIPort in it so you can start working right away...

Comment: Thanks Bernat. I got the image, used the same settings to initialize JVM in Pharo2.0 image, and i got the random long working. Its a start. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

JNIPort is unlikely to work in a recent Pharo right now. There have been significant changes in FFI (NativeBoost, etc) that have not been ported yet to JNIPort. At the Esug conference Johan Brichau said something about making it work again, but I don't know how far that work is. Better take a look in the pharo dev mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

JNIPort has been adapted to Pharo 3 and 5 ca. 2014 (JNIPort release 3.1-alpha). The sources are at SmalltalkHub. From what I see at http://www.smalltalkhub.com/JNIPort/JNIPort/mc/ it seems that Denis Kudryashov has adapted it to Pharo 6. It could be that his version works with later Pharo releases as well.
Unfortunately, I haven't had enough spare time to continue supporting JNIPort. The licence allows everyone to update it. If you do so, just keep me informed, such that I can update the documentation with version information and links to the sites where more recent versions of JNIPort can be downloaded.